# WooCommerce - Change product quantities in shipping classes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce, I'm currently coding a plugin where customers can pre-order products. This also includes scenarios where customers can purchase what is currently in stock plus pre-order stock. E.g. 2 bikes are in stock, 5 more will be available at a later point. The customer can purchase all these together.

Now the shipping fee is supposed to be calculated based on what is in stock. If a customer would purchase only pre-order stock, they will not have to pay any shipping for these products.

So if you add all 7 bikes to the cart, it is only supposed to calculate shipping for 2 bikes.

The filter hook `woocommerce_package_rates` seems good for generally unsetting shipping classes (which I don't want), adding taxes or defining a new shipping price **but I can't seem to adjust the product quantity in there.**

So where or how can I alter product specific quantity of a shipping class?

---

**Related shipping method settings:**

For this scenario lets say every two items the prices jumps 100€. So now it calculates all 7 bikes  (400€), while it should only calculate the 2 instock bikes (100€). *But this is just one scenario, I'm looking to adjust this for a lot of different ones.*

---

**Edit** - Maybe helpful:

I have this array inside the `cart_item` metadata which I also tried using inside the `woocommerce_package_rates` filter hook.

It goes like this:

```
$cart_item['restock_list'] = {
  current_qty => 7,
  instock => 2,
  restocks => {
    restock_id (int) => {
      stock => 5,
      arrival => 214472472 (unix timestamp)
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Updated my question. We’re using the Table Rate Shipping plugin to set our shipping methods. It holds a lot of very different settings for the various shipping classes:  At times there is a price for every second or third item, sometimes there is a start price with an additional fee for every added item, sometimes it just has a start price, etc…
That’s why I was thinking of altering the item quantity of the shipping classes instead of writing my own shipping cost calculations. It would also make the code more flexible. Open to other suggestions.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thank you for this suggestion but it's unfortunately not really viable for a website with a lot of shipping zones and classes.  If I would set it up the way you suggested, I would always need to adjust the different ways quantities are multiplied programmatically or write really a lot of new code just for shipping. This wouldn't be workable for a store manager as well.